# Wrap content not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

```
**item_my_message.xml**

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@android:color/transparent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="72dp"
    android:background="@drawable/my_message_style"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_mymessge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView_time"
        android:text="asdasd"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryBackgorund" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView_mymessge"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:text="12:00 pm"
        android:paddingRight="6dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorHint"
        android:textSize="12dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>


package pruebas.integra.Activites;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.TimeZone;

import pruebas.integra.Adapters.MensajeAdapter;
import pruebas.integra.Models.ConversationModel;
import pruebas.integra.R;

public class ChatConversationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Context context;
TextView textViewNombre;
TextView textViewEstado;
ImageView imgEstado;
EditText mensaje;
MensajeAdapter mensajeAdapter;
Button btnEnviarMensaje;
ArrayList<ConversationModel> mensajeChat;
ListView listView;
Calendar c;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat_conversation);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    context = this;
    c = Calendar.getInstance();

    imgEstado = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView_state);
    String nombre = getIntent().getExtras().getString("value");
    Boolean state = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("estado");
    textViewEstado = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_state);
    if (state == true) {
        textViewEstado.setText("Conectado");
             textViewEstado.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_green_light));
        imgEstado.setColorFilter((context.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_green_light)));

    } else {
        textViewEstado.setText("Desconectado");
        textViewEstado.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryBackgorund));
        imgEstado.setColorFilter(R.color.colorPrimaryBackgorund);
    }

    final TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
    textViewNombre = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtchatNombre);
    textViewNombre.setText(nombre);

    btnEnviarMensaje = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_enviarmensaje);
    mensajeChat = new ArrayList<ConversationModel>();
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView_mensajes_conversacion);
    mensaje = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_mensaje);

    mensajeAdapter = new MensajeAdapter(context, mensajeChat);
    listView.setAdapter(mensajeAdapter);

    btnEnviarMensaje.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mensaje.getText().toString() == null && mensaje.getText().toString() == " ") {

            } else {
                ConversationModel conversation = new ConversationModel();
                //mensaje.getText().append("\ud83d\ude01"); //EMOJI
                conversation.setMensaje(mensaje.getText().toString());
                String temp = Integer.toString(c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)) + ":" + Integer.toString(c.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
                conversation.setTime(temp);
                mensajeChat.add(conversation);
                mensajeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                mensaje.setText("");
                listView.smoothScrollToPosition(mensajeAdapter.getCount());
            }
        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();
}
```

}

I've got an item which I'm using for a chat, the thing is that the wrap content is not working, the layout itself stays at a certain width not according to its content I don't seem to find why is it doing that.

[This is how it looks, it is supposed to wrap the content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cbrf.png)

Comment: Put `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` in the first `RelativeLayout`

Comment: it still looks the same :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not fully understand what are you asking But I think The problem is  for first `textView` You have

```
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
```

**And** for the second one

```
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

for the second `textView` do not use align parent property But use

```
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView_mymessge"
```

if you want `time` to the right of message **OR** use

```
android:layout_below="@+id/textView_mymessge"
```

if you want `time` below to the message.

Comment: Thanks, and also `layout_alignLeft/Right="@id/x"` is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you specify `wrap_content` for a `view` or `ViewGroup` for which a drawable (in your case its `"@drawable/my_message_style"` ) is being used as the `android:background`, the view takes up the size of the image being used.
The solution is to reduce the size of the drawable you are using as the background of your `RelativeLayout`. Or you can simply use a color, its easier that way. Hope this helps